# Images not being set programmatically in KDCircularProgress

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, storyboard, kdcircularprogress

I am trying to set an image inside  [KDCircularProgress](https://github.com/kaandedeoglu/KDCircularProgress) which is placed inside a UITableViewCell.

[image]

When I add an image from StoryBoard it successfully shows, but when I try to add it programatically the image does not appear.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cellToReturn: DashBoardCell! = tableView .dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DashBoardCell") as? DashBoardCell
    if (cellToReturn == nil) {
        cellToReturn = DashBoardCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:"DashBoardCell")
    }
    let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "ImageName")!
    dImage = UIImageView(image: image)
    dImage!.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,30,25)
    dImage?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
    cellToReturn.dynamicImageView = dImage
```

dynamicImageView is the UIImageView outlet in UITableViewCell class and I am trying to set the dynamic image in table view cell in the View Controller class in which the TableView delegate methods are implemented.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what `DashBoardCell` looks like so this may be wrong, but it appears that `dImage` is never added to the view hierarchy. If the `DashBoardCell` has already created `dynamicImageView` in your storyboard, and I don't see why it wouldn't, then you don't need to worry about creating a `UIImageView`, you could simply set the image like

```
cellToReturn.dynamicImageView.image = UIImage(named: "ImageName")
```

If it hasn't, then you'll want to add it with something like

```
cellToReturn.contentView.addSubview(dImage)
```

Or if `DashBoardCell`'s `dynamicImageView` has a `didSet` observer you could insert the new view there. You'll also want to make sure you override `prepareForReuse` in `DashBoardCell` to remove `dynamicImageView` since you'll be creating a new one in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.